# Function to shift array elements not working

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11

I have a null terminated array of chars. Also known as a c-string. I have written a function that will shift the elements at each index left, <---- by a given number of indexes. For example, when the char array of "hello world" is passed to the function, with a shiftBy value of 3, it should transform the char array to be: "lo worldhel".

Currently, this function works for all strings that <= 11 elelements. Anything over that and the last three spots in the array don't get shifted. Keep in mind, the very last index is holding the null terminator!

This is a tricky one and I have been stuck for hours. I also can't use any standard functions or vectors, I am stuck with these deprecated arrays and simple loops. So please don't troll with "Why don;t you use blank function"....because trust me, if I could I wouldn't be here.

Here is the code, have at at:

```
    void shiftLeft (char szString[], int size, int shiftBy)
{
    if(shiftBy > size){
        shiftBy = shiftBy - size;
    }

    if(size == 1){
        //do nothing, do nothing, exit function with no change made to myarray
    }
    else{
        char temp;
        //for loop to print the array with indexes moved up (to the left) <-- by 2
        for (int i = 0; i <= size-shiftBy; i++)//size = 11
        {//EXAMPLE shift by 3  for a c-string of `hello world`
            if(i < size-shiftBy){
                temp = szString[shiftBy + i];//temp = h
                szString[shiftBy + i] = szString[i];//d becomes l
                szString[i] = temp;//h becomes l
            }
            else{//it will run once while i=8
                temp = szString[i];//temp = l
                szString[i] = szString[i+1];//8th element becomes h
                szString[i+1] = szString[size-1];//9th element becomes e
                szString[size-1] = temp;//last element becomes l

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: google rotate array http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/case8.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the only purpose you're trying to accomplish is shifting chars in a terminated string left *with rotation* (and judging by your sample of `"helloworld"` resulting in `"loworldhel"` after a 3-shift, that seems to be the case), you're making this *much* harder than it needs to be.

The traditional algorithm to do this in O(N) time with no temporary space requirements is to reverse the left-side of the shift, then the entire sequence, then the right side of the shift, *all* based from the beginning of the sequence. For example, suppose we want to left-shift the following string 3 slots:

```
1234567890
```

First, reverse the first shiftBy slots

```
1234567890
^-^
3214567890
```

Second, reverse the entire sequence

```
3214567890
^--------^
0987654123
```

Finally, reverse the (length-shiftBy) slots:

```
0987654123
^-----^
4567890123
```

Using the standard library would make this **trivial**, but apparently you're prof considers that... cheating. Without using *any* library apis the above algorithm isn't very hard regardless:

```
#include <iostream>

void shiftLeft(char sz[], size_t shiftBy)
{
    const char *p = sz;
    while (*p) ++p;
    std::size_t len = p - sz;

    if (len > 1 && (shiftBy %= len))
    {
        char *ends[] = { sz+shiftBy, sz+len, sz+(len - shiftBy) };
        for (std::size_t i=0; i<3; ++i)
        {
            char *start = sz, *end = ends[i];
            while (start < --end)
            {
                char ch = *start;
                *start++ = *end;
                *end = ch;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char sz[] = "1234567890";
    std::cout << sz << '\n';

    shiftLeft(sz, 11);
    std::cout << sz << '\n';

    shiftLeft(sz, 4);
    std::cout << sz << '\n';

    shiftLeft(sz, 1);
    std::cout << sz << '\n';

    shiftLeft(sz, 20);
    std::cout << sz << '\n';
}
```

**Output**

```
1234567890
2345678901
6789012345
7890123456
7890123456
```

If you're really set on doing this in temp space, so be it, but I cannot possibly fathom why you would do so.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you, this is also a fantastic and helpful answer. I also like that you inadvertently made a smiley faces. ^-^

Comment: @DracoM. So long as you understand the concept behind it, its all good. Glad it helped. I just hope I explained the algorithm well enough.

Answer (score 0):

From  azillionmonkeys.com/qed/case8.html

```
void shiftLeft(char szString[], int size, int shiftBy) {
            int c, tmp, v;

            if (size <= 0) return;
            if (shiftBy < 0 || shiftBy >= size) {
                shiftBy %= size;
                if (shiftBy < 0) shiftBy += size;
            }
            if (shiftBy == 0) return;

            c = 0;
            for (v = 0; c < size; v++) {
                int t = v, tp = v + shiftBy;
                char tmp = szString[v];
                c++;
                while (tp != v) {
                    szString[t] = szString[tp];
                    t = tp;
                    tp += shiftBy;
                    if (tp >= size) tp -= size;
                    c++;
                }
                szString[t] = tmp;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I am very concerned why there is a `return` statement in the middle of this `void` function.

Comment: Not an error at all.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249108/can-i-return-in-void-function

Comment: Damn it, I concede. I got this to work and it works flawlessly. I wasn't the one who downvoted this answer, but I sure will upvote it. Thanks for the help and sorry for the poor attitude. Thanks to you I can finally go to bed mate. Also I will study it more in depth tomorrow, and try my best to learn from it.