# When is it useful to return a void function from another void function in C++?

Tags: c++

This code is legal:

```
void bar() {}

void foo() {
    return bar();
}
```

You can't assign anything to a void object, so why would you want to return a void?

EDIT: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35987493/return-void-type-in-c-and-c) question is not related to this question. It is asking if returning void is legal. I'm asking when you would ever want to return void.

Comment: It simplifies writing template code where the template parameter can be `void` or something else. Then you don't have to add special cases for void

Comment: @beangod Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35987493/return-void-type-in-c-and-c

Comment: Note, you are not returning a void function, you are returning the result of a void function.

Comment: This code is not valid in C++.

Comment: @n.m. how is it invalid?

Comment: @n.m it has been valid since c++98

Comment: Sorry my bad, it is legal.

Comment: Voting to re-open.  The other question is about whether returning a void expression is legal.  This is about _when_ it would be useful.  Also, the other question is a mishmash of C and C++, and this one is better focused.

Comment: @M.M please write it up as an answer.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Better dupe [C++: return the return value of a void function from a void function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37009695/c-return-the-return-value-of-a-void-function-from-a-void-function) and here is some more related [Can I return in void function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249108/can-i-return-in-void-function)

Comment: More accurate duplicate: [Return void function value from a void function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37009842/19946454)