# C2120 when using return in a void slot in Qt C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, qt5

When I put *return;* or *return void();* in a regular void method of the C++ class in Qt 5 it compiles ok. When I put it in a *slots* method the compiler generates the following error:

> error C2120: 'void' illegal with all types

Here it is stated, that a return in void is possible: [Can I return in void function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249108/can-i-return-in-void-function)

Here it is stated, that since slots are normal C++ functions one may return value, including void, I presume.
http://www.qtcentre.org/archive/index.php/t-26724.html

Any ideas why a C2120 is issued under those circumstances?

Comment: Which compiler and version is this? Can you reproduce it on an online compiler?

Comment: Don't worry about it; this question will be closed as off-topic anyway since it's a simple mistake that was easily debugged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can only return void from a void function. For example:

```
void foo()
{
  return void();
}
```

else you can return like

```
void foo()
{
  return;
}
```

which is void in itself.

as stated in that example, but you cannot return anything else, That is why there is an error.

Comment: The question says that the error is triggered by returning `void`, not "anything else."