# Wrapping a callable that may be void return

Tags: c++, closures, c++17

Say I have some wrapper function, in which I'd like to do some setup, call a callback (and save its result), do some cleanup, and then return what the callback returned:

```
#include <functional>
#include <utility>

template<class F, typename... Args>
decltype(auto) wrap(F&& func, Args&... args) {
    // Do some stuff before
    auto result = std::invoke(std::forward<decltype(func)>(func),
                              std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    // Do some stuff after
    return result;
}
```

A practical example of this is a timer utility function that returns the elapsed time of the function call as well as its return value (in a tuple, perhaps).

Such a function works fine for callables with return types:

```
void foo() {
    auto a = 1;
    wrap([](auto a) { return 1; }, a);
}
```

But with a callable with void return type, during the template specialization the compiler complains that `auto result` has incomplete type void:

```
void foo() {
    auto a = 1;
    wrap([](auto a) {}, a);
}
```

This makes sense of course, because [while you can `return void()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249108/can-i-return-in-void-function), you can't store it in a variable.

I want `wrap` to work for both kinds of callables. I've attempted using `std::function` to give two signatures for `wrap`:

1. `template<class T, typename... Args> decltype(auto) wrap(std::function<T(Args...)>, Args&... args)`
2. `template<typename... Args> decltype(auto) wrap(std::function<void(Args...)>, Args&... args)`

The first of those will continue to match callables with a non-`void` return, but the latter fails to match those with return type `void`.

Is there a way to make wrap work in both the return type `void` and non-`void` callable cases?

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer, but this sounds like an `std::optional` use case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way I like to solve this problem is with [regular void](https://medium.com/@barryrevzin/without-form-and-void-cfc62091d4d6). Well, we don't actually have proper regular `void`, but we can make our own type `Void` that is regular, that is kind of like `void`. And then provide a wrapper around `invoke` that understands that.

The shortest version (there's more detail in that blog):

```
struct Void { };

template <typename F, typename ...Args,
    typename Result = std::invoke_result_t<F, Args...>,
    std::enable_if_t<!std::is_void_v<Result>, int> = 0>
Result invoke_void(F&& f, Args&& ...args) {
    return std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

// void case
template <typename F, typename ...Args,
    typename Result = std::invoke_result_t<F, Args...>,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_void_v<Result>, int> = 0>
Void invoke_void(F&& f, Args&& ...args) {
    std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    return Void();
}
```

This lets you, in your original code, do:

```
template<class F, typename... Args>
decltype(auto) wrap(F&& func, Args&... args) {
    // Do some stuff before
    auto result = invoke_void(std::forward<decltype(func)>(func),
                              std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    // Do some stuff after
    return result;
}
```

And this works, even if `func` returns `void`.

Comment: That's clever. Although, the fact that you need to do such contortions for something so straightforward is really disappointing. I was about to ask about the (inconsequential but irksome) fact that for `void` `func`, wrap's return type is `Void` instead of `void`, but the article you linked to suggests an elegant way of casting out of that using `std::conditional_t`. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @BaileyParker Yeah, [this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0146r1.html) would be better. But this is what we have today.

Comment: I just read your blog post.  Very nice!  However, I think you could just mark `Void` as `final` so you don't need the SFINAEing constructor.

Comment: @Henri That's a pretty weak reason to use `final`, imo. If you're going to prevent potentially valuable uses of your type, you'd better get more value than "slightly less typing in one constructor"

Comment: @Barry But `Void` is just there to encapsulate `void` and since you can't derive from `void` why would you ever want to derive from `Void`? Deriving from something that represents “not a type” doesn't make a lot of sense to me, but I'm open to other opinions.

Comment: @Henri Well, you can't have an object of type `void` either, so drawing comparisons from there doesn't get you anywhere. `void` does not represent "not a type" - it most certainly is a type. It is _the_ unit type.

Answer (score 4):

If the “Do some stuff after” does not use the `result` variable you could avoid SFINAE by using your favourite scope guard library.  I have provided a very naïve implementation here but you can find more elaborate ones online.

```
#include <functional>

template <typename F>
struct ScopeExit_impl {
    F f;
    ScopeExit_impl(F f) : f(std::move(f)) {}
    ~ScopeExit_impl() noexcept { f(); }
};

template <typename F>
ScopeExit_impl<F> ScopeExit(F &&f) {
    return ScopeExit_impl<F>{std::forward<F>(f)};
}

template <class F, typename... Args>
decltype(auto) wrap(F &&func, Args &... args) {
    // Do some stuff before
    auto exit = ScopeExit([&]() {
        // Do some stuff after
    });
    return std::invoke(std::forward<decltype(func)>(func),
                       std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main() {
    auto a = 1;
    wrap([](auto a) { return 1; }, a);
    wrap([](auto a) {}, a);
}
```